# getting containers to work with config files build through ansible templatizing

Tags: docker, ansible

I use ansible to push out custom services, as well as template out configuration files for those applications (different for each application/server/environment)

I'm moving to Docker to run my services, but still need to utilize the configuration files that are being pushed by ansible.

So for now, I am allowing ansible to push the configuration templates to the remote host, and then mounting the configuration directory as a volume in the container, to give the service running in the container access to that configuration data.

This hacky solution requires 3 separated things be in alignment for things to work (ansible pushing the config file to the right path, the container to properly mount that path as a volume, and the application finding the configuration at the mount location) -- this screams high-risk, hard-to-manage and hard-to-change.

What are some *better* ways to get the ansible-templatized configuration files available to the container? Or do I need to start pursuing alternatives to ansible?

Some thoughts:

- I have a lot of different VMs and application sets across dev/qa/prod
  environments, so I don't want to pursue baking configuration into the
  images or I'll end up with hundreds of images
- I'm okay with loading the configuration at container-run-time, but how could I do this in a way to still take advantage of ansibles templatizing short of running ansible playbook from within the container on itself (somehow?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you're following now seems like a good one, actually, and I probably wouldn't change anything.

Since a Docker container has an isolated filesystem, it's common for containers to use fixed "normal" filesystem paths.  For instance, the [standard nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) is littered with references to `/etc/nginx` in container space.  It's reasonable to treat these container-side paths as part of the external interface to an image; you should treat the path `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as being as stable as the command-line option `-g 'daemon off'` (you don't expect this path to change across image updates).

To avoid repeating the file path you could use an Ansible [variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html).  This could be more useful if you had a role per container you're launching.  You could supply a default host-side path, and override it in a top-level playbook or at the command line.  That would let you write a container-launching playbook like

```
- name: Copy nginx.conf
  template:
    src: nginx.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ nginx_config_path }}/nginx.conf"

- name: Launch nginx
  docker_container:
    name: nginx
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - "{{ nginx_config_path }}:/etc/nginx"
```

Note that this problem isn't especially unique to Ansible.  A [kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes) ConfigMap object is the closest equivalent to this, and like what you're describing here it's also the right path to inject config files into containers (Pods), but it has essentially the same problem of needing three pairs of names to match up.  Again, there's not really a better solution than trying to use a "variable" or "constant" to the extent your orchestration system allows it and hope the problem gets caught sooner rather than later.